# Firebug extension context.sourceCache.load(href) returns 'Reload the page to get source for: http://'

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

Firefox 32.0.1
Firebug 2.0.4
Windows 7

I'm writing Fx extension for Firebug and this code:
`Firebug.currentContext.sourceCache.load(href)` returns "Reload the page to get source for: http://domain.com/style.css"

Any ideas why?

Comment: Such specific questions may better be asked within the [Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/firebug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will happen always unless the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) is enabled. I suggest doing something like [`loadFromSourceCache()` in `content/firebug/debugger/script/sourceFile.js`](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/f5f027cb4fc1ef31062e07298a353213cad15527/extension/content/firebug/debugger/script/sourceFile.js#L166).

Also, do note https://github.com/firebug/firebug.next/ - it might be better to build your extension on top of the built-in devtools instead of on Firebug.